# jQuery and asynchronous calls

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, async-await, c#-5.0

When using a jQuery client side function to call an MVC controller method, **do I need to decorate my MVC method with the asynchronous Task async, and await keywords** since the jQuery call is **already** inherently an asynchronous call?

Comment: AJAX predates C# 5.0. How do you think it worked before, if doing this was necessary? And how does it work in, say, PHP, which doesn't have any support for asynchrony?

Answer (score 5):

The HTTP protocol is always the same, it doesn't change when you use asynchronous code on your server and it also doesn't change when you use asynchronous code on the client.

What this means is that you can use asynchronous calls from your JavaScript to any action on the server, it doesn't matter whether it's asynchronous itself or not.

Comment: So, do I also need to include the Task, async, await on the server side or is this redundant? Still don't know if I should do this or not.

Comment: What if I want to load several listboxes on the page via jquery/ajax calls or even just a separate database call. Do I need to include the Task, async, await in the controller method ?

Comment: @sagesky No, you don't need async for that.

Comment: So, the only time I need to use Task, async, await is if I'm making a DB call, etc WITHOUT jQuery/AJAX?

Comment: @sagesky36 `async`-`await` is completely unrelated (orthogonal) to AJAX. Pretty much the only when `async`-`await` is useful in ASP.NET is if you're doing a DB call or something like that.

Comment: But that's exactly what I'm saying... I'm telling you that when I do a DB call, I can include the async-await. But just before, you informed me that it was not necessary if I'm using a jQuery/AJAX call to the DB. Which one is it?

Comment: @sagesky36 Whether you should use async doesn't depend on whether you're using AJAX on the client or not. It depends only on what the server does.

Answer (score 4):

It does not depends on this thing, Async Controller puropose is some different, what is does is after receiving request it frees the request thread immeditely so that maximumn requests can be entertained by server and after the Task is completed it calls back the thread which invoked it, and will return response to it.

Async Controller is useful when we have to do heavy I/O operation so, we use it so that after recieving request in IIS it releases the thread immedtiately and thread is called again when response is ready to be returned.

you can read more here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/526099/Asynchronous-Controller-in-ASP-NET-MVC
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.asynccontroller%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

by using async controllers performance is also improved of application, you can read more in detail here:

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/25/measuring-the-performance-of-asynchronous-controllers/

What you are talking of jquery ajax, it purpose is to do operation in other thread not in the browser Ui thread so that our application remains reponsive, if ajax call takes for example 2 minutes and you have not jquery ajax with async:false, your application will stuck until ajax call completes operation. but if its async your application will be responsive for user.

Hope it helps and guides you in right direction..:)

Comment: Basically using async controllers in asp.net making request processing very similar to what node.js is doing.

Comment: what node.js do @vittore?? i never used it till

Comment: Well in short node.js has event loop and non blocking IO, so when request comes and your code start processing it and starts some IO intensive operation in a non-blocking maner, node.js can handle new request already and return to processing previous one as soon as IO operation is finished. Same thing is happening with async controllers, you can handle new request while previous one is still in process.

Comment: Read this great article from wintellect http://wintellect.com/blogs/jlane/five-reasons-asp.net-developers-shouldn%E2%80%99t-worry-about-node

Comment: Thanks @vittore should we use node.js with asp.net mvc?

Comment: They are two different beasts, however you can host node.js app side by side with asp.net mvc app in the same IIS. Article I linked will give you more detailed overview. So short answer is no.

Comment: This part is wrong: "it do the work in a seperate thread". Asynchronous controller do not just push off work to a separate thread; ideally, they free up the request thread *without* requiring another thread.

Comment: What if I want to load several listboxes on the page via jquery/ajax calls or even just a separate database call. Do I need to include the Task, async, await in the controller method ?

Comment: if it takes more time than normal ajax call, then you can go for Task async, otherwise its ok

Comment: Seems to be two different opinions here if you look at the next answer. I'll post the same question to you. So, the only time I need to use Task, async, await is if I'm making a DB call, etc WITHOUT jQuery/AJAX?

Comment: If you expect that operation can be take long time than normal request,  because when request sent a request thread is picked from iis and in your long operation request thread will be occupied and if 100 users for example request the same request,  it will be a issue

Comment: So, you're saying then that it's ok to use the async-await in conjunction with a jquery/AJAX call. Correct?

Comment: Yes you can say yes in a way